# Convert very small double values to string (with scientific notation) (Java)

Tags: java, double, scientific-notation

I'm trying to print a small *double* number like `6.67e-11`, but using Double.toString() returns `0`. What can I do to make it print 6.67e-11 (or something similar) instead?

Comment: Please take a look at [`DecimalFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unable to reproduce:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        double d = 6.67e-11;

        System.out.println(Double.toString(d)); // Prints "6.67E-11"
    }
}
```

IIRC, `Double.toString()` always returns a string which allows the exact value to be round-tripped using `Double.parseDouble()`.

My guess is that you don't *actually* have a small value - that you have 0, due to some rounding errors in other operations.

Comment: +1 - The javadoc confirms your recollection: *"How many digits must be printed for the fractional part of m or a? There must be at least one digit to represent the fractional part, and beyond that as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of type double."*

Comment: Damnit, you're right. Double.toString() was working as I wanted, the bug was in another part of the code. I Guess I should have tested more before asking...